# MVC SimpleInjector tries to inject in every constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have a MVC project, where i want to register a singleton of a specific service.

When i use simpleinjector, i get an error in all of my other classes with multiple constructors and so on. How do i configure it so ONLY my wanted service is dependency injection and DI is disabled for everything else (like before i used the DI container)?

Example of an exception i get:

> No registration for type AccountController could be found and an
>   implicit registration could not be made. For the container to be able
>   to create AccountController it should have only one public
>   constructor: it has 2.

But i don't want *AccountController* to use dependency injection?!

```
public partial class Startup
{

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Create IOC Container
        var container = new Container();
        // Register services
        container.RegisterSingleton<IWebSocketHandler, WebSocketHandler>();
        // Verify services
        container.Verify();

        // Store the container for use by the application
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));    
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? Why are you using a DI Container when you don't want a container to compose your object graphs?

Comment: @Steven I just want a singleton of my IWebSocketHandler to be accesible in the whole application (MVC project and class libraries).

Comment: "all of my other classes with multiple constructors". Your application components should _not_ have multiple constructors, as clearly expressed [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).